# Using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of the limit, evaluate, $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=x^2$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of the limit, evaluate $$\lim\limits_ {x\to a}f(x)=x^2$$

I am stuck on $|x−a||x+a|<\epsilon$ and can't eliminate $|x+a|$.

Comment: Welcome to this site. In the future, you could use the approach0 search engine to search for existing questions, so that you end with less duplicate questions.  And, please do not delete questions right after you received an answer, like one of the last questions you deleted.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$
|x+a| = |(x-a)+2a| \leq |x-a| + 2|a|
$$